# How to enable on-screen keyboard?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have one screen. it consists of an edit text.
I want when this screen shown  on the screen, keypad automatically shown by default without clicking on the edit text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your App Manifest.xml file, you can set the soft keyboard status.  Sounds like you want to set it to "stateVisible" or "stateAlwaysVisible"

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=["stateUnspecified",
                                   "stateUnchanged", "stateHidden",
                                   "stateAlwaysHidden", "stateVisible",
                                   "stateAlwaysVisible", "adjustUnspecified",
                                   "adjustResize", "adjustPan"] >
```